# Add Custom filter to User admin list

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying one custom column called `company name` in default user listing page. Now i want to filter that user listing page by that column name `company name`. How i can add my custom filter (one of `meta_key`) to filter default listing of user by using my column.
Please find image for more clarity -

[image]

```
//Code to filter user list by Status
function admin_users_filter( $query ){
global $pagenow,$wp_query;

if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && isset($_GET['abc']) && $_GET['abc'] != '') {
   $query->search_term = urldecode($_GET['abc']);

   global $wpdb;

    if (!is_null($query->search_term)) {

      $query = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT DISTINCT account_status FROM wp_custom_user_details ORDER BY account_status ASC " );

    }    
}
}

add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'admin_users_filter' );


add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'restrict_abc_manage_list' );
function restrict_abc_manage_list()
{
?>
<select name="abc" style="float: none;">
    <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By Status', 'baapf'); ?></option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="2">Inactive</option>


 </select> 
 <input id="post-query-submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Filter" name="">
<?php  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Eek have given the solution to add custom column in users list. so i am giving how to add filter for 'Company' option .the code is given

```
function admin_users_filter( $query ){
global $pagenow,$wp_query;

if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && isset($_GET['abc']) && $_GET['abc'] != '') {
   $query->search_term = urldecode($_GET['abc']);

   global $wpdb;

    if (!is_null($query->search_term)) {

      $query->query_from .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON " . 
        "{$wpdb->users}.ID={$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id AND " .
        "{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='meta_key_name_here' AND "."{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value LIKE '%{$query->search_term}%'";

    }    
}
}

add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'admin_users_filter' );


add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'restrict_abc_manage_list' );
function restrict_abc_manage_list()
{
?>
<select name="abc" style="float: none;">
    <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By College', 'baapf'); ?></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

 </select> 
 <input id="post-query-submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Filter" name="">
<?php  
}
```

find any doubt then ask...thxs

Comment: this code is working properly for me. now you need to customize value related to college according to your need...thxs

Comment: If i am using "verify,not-verify" and all instead of 1,2,3 in options box than i am unable to do filtering.

Comment: there is relation between wp_users and wp_custom_user_details.so what is relation column please share. actually where you write query "SELECT DISTINCT account_status FROM wp_custom_user_details ORDER BY account_status ASC " " it is not good way to fetch data without any relation to "wp_users" table

Comment: wp_users's ID is user_id column in my wp_custom_user_details.

Comment: please replace my below function "admin_users_filter" to your function "admin_users_filter".        function admin_users_filter( $query ){
global $pagenow,$wp_query;if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && isset($_GET['abc']) && $_GET['abc'] != '') {
   $query->search_term = $_GET['abc'];

   global $wpdb;

    if (!is_null($query->search_term)) {

      $query->query_from .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->custom_user_details} ON " . 
        "{$wpdb->users}.ID={$wpdb->custom_user_details}.user_id AND " .
        "{$wpdb->custom_user_details}.account_status='$query->search_term' ";

    }    
}
}

Comment: I got this working after replacing `pre_user_query` with `pre_get_users`. See here for more details why https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184936/pre-user-query-meta-query-admin-user-list

Answer (score 2):

Be careful.
"restrict_manage_users" hook doesn't work properly in WordPress4.4 or above.
(There's the same issue in latest 4.8)

The solution is bellow.
http://www.linsoftware.com/using-the-restrict_manage_users-action-hook-in-wordpress-4-4/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the admin_init hook to load a function that creates a class for adding a sorting columns in the admin :) Drop it in functions.php in your theme file.

```
if(!function_exists("load_sortable_user_meta_columns")){
    add_action('admin_init', 'load_sortable_user_meta_columns');
    function load_sortable_user_meta_columns(){
        //THIS IS WHERE YOU ADD THE meta_key => display-title values, you can add multiple args, ex: array('company'=>'Company', 'user_registered'=>'Date Registered');
        $args = array('company'=>'Company');
        new sortable_user_meta_columns($args);
    }
}
if(!class_exists("sortable_user_meta_columns")):
class sortable_user_meta_columns{
    var $defaults = array('nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered','user_nicename', 'user_email', 'user_url', 'user_registered','display_name','name','post_count','ID','id','user_login');
    //By things in user_meta
    function __construct($args){
        $this->args = $args;
        add_action('pre_user_query', array(&$this, 'query'));
        add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  array(&$this, 'content'), 10, 3);
        add_filter('manage_users_columns', array(&$this, 'columns'));
        add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', array(&$this, 'sortable') );
    }
    function query($query){
        $vars = $query->query_vars;
        if(in_array($vars['orderby'], $this->defaults)) return;
        $title = $this->args[$vars['orderby']];
        if(!empty($title)){
               $query->query_from .= " LEFT JOIN bib_usermeta m ON (bib_users.ID = m.user_id  AND m.meta_key = '$vars[orderby]')";
               $query->query_orderby = "ORDER BY m.meta_value ".$vars['order'];
        }
    }
    function columns($columns) {
        foreach($this->args as $key=>$value){
            $columns[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $columns;
    }
    function sortable($columns){
        foreach($this->args as $key=>$value){
            $columns[$key] = $key;
        }
        return $columns;
    }
    function content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
            $user = get_userdata( $user_id ); //Get the content of the custom meta
            return $user->$column_name; //Get the custom meta. Eg: Company
    }
}
endif;
```

This example will work if you meta_key is 'company' if it's 'company_name' you'll have to change it in $args. eg: `$args = array('company_name' => 'Company Name');`

:)

Comment: i have already created column name say company_name but what i want is to create filter that will filter by company name.

Comment: The class is used for sorting, you can copy the class and initiate it with your custom args eg: `$args = array('company_name' => 'Company Name'); new sortable_user_meta_columns($args);` You'll need to do this at `admin_init` time.